# Exercise II 3.22 Hartshrone: would like a clarification of the statement

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

In Exercise II 3.22 Hartshorne says let $f:X \to Y$ be a dominant morphism of integral schemes of finite type over a field.

Let $k$ be a field. 
I just wanted to verify that this actually means (1) $f$ is dominant (2) $X$ and $Y$ are integral schemes of finite type over $k$?

I was getting slightly confused with the wording, and I just wanted to make sure I had the right meaning. I think it's unlikely but I thought maybe $X$ is an integral schemes of finite type over $k_1$ and $Y$ is an integral scheme of finite type over $k_2$, where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are different fields?. Or possibly that this means $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of integral schemes and this $f$ is of finite type..

Any clarification would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "of finite type" is a property of $f$. See the definitions that precede example 3.2.1. And yes, $X$ and $Y$ are integral schemes over the same field $k$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Thank you for your comment. Are you saying the same thing as in the answer by EricWolfsey, or do you mean that $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of finite type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is almost correct: $X$ and $Y$ are each integral schemes of finite type over $k$, and $f:X\to Y$ is a dominant morphism *of schemes over $k$* (so, it forms a commutative diagram with the morphisms to $\operatorname{Spec} k$).  In general, when one speaks of a "morphism of [...] schemes over $T$", then that means a morphism in the category of schemes over $T$ rather than just the category of schemes.

Comment: This makes more sense, thank you!

Comment: One could also add that a morphism $f: X \to Y$ where $X, Y$ are of finite type over $k$, is also a morphism of finite type.